# WordPress : Get the Actual Count of A Custom Loop’s Returned Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm doing a query:

It is possible that get the actual count of returned posts,I use this:

```
$sitens = new wp_query( array ( 'post_type' => 'post' , 'post__in' => array($post_id) ) );
$numResults = $sitens->post_count; 
if ( $sitens->have_posts() ) : while ( $sitens->have_posts() ) : $sitens->the_post();
echo $numResults;
endwhile; endif;
```

If the `$post_id = ('44','53','4453');`

it must be the value of `$numResults` = 3 ,

But its show me 1;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use $sitens->found_posts; instead. I believe post_count shows the amount of posts being displayed while found_posts shows the total number of posts returned by the query.

Comment: Try setting your $post_id variable to $post_id = array( 44 , 53 , 4453 );  (note the absence of quotes) and then for your WP_Query parameter 'post__in' => $post_id